# How to force creation of new ContentPartRecords for existing content items?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I have created a new ContentPart with a ContentPartRecord in a custom module and attached it to an existing content type on my website that already has hundreds of content items.

Now when I perform queries of the format `contentManager.Query<MyPart, MyPartRecord>().List()` I don't get any results since no MyPartRecords actually exist in the database yet.

Is there a way to make sure this happens for all content as soon as my part gets attached to a content type, or will I have to manually interact with all of the items before they become queryable?

Comment: This query is asking for all content items that have that part, which is not the case of items created before you added the part to the type definition. See the type definition as a blueprint more than a schema. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may want to try to query by content type instead.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy It's mainly for performance reasons that I would like to query this way, and because the part could be attached to multiple content types, but I realize now that I'm asking a bad question. What I really need to know is at what point Orchard decides to create the record, which I could discover by studying the source, and if I I can manually do this once without causing too much overhead. I don't think Orchard provides an opportunity to do this out of the box (i.e. there is no such thing as an "OnAttached" event for content definitions).

Comment: The part will get attached next time the item gets updated, pretty much. You *could* build  something that scripts the operation on existing items, but nothing out of the box will do that.

Comment: Upgrading that to an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is asking for all content items that have that part, which is not the case of items created before you added the part to the type definition. See the type definition as a blueprint more than a schema. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may want to try to query by content type instead.

The part will get attached next time the item gets updated, pretty much. You could build something that scripts the operation on existing items, but nothing out of the box will do that.